# Set minutes of timestamp to a specific value

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, timestamp

What is the easiest way to set the exact minutes value of a timestamp?

This only adds minutes instead of setting the exact value:

```
SELECT timestamp_field + interval '2 minutes';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`date_trunc()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) before you add 2 minutes:

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', timestamp_field) + interval '2 minutes';
```

Or, to retain seconds and sub-seconds:

```sql
SELECT date_trunc('hour', timestamp_field)
     + interval '2 min'
     + extract('seconds' FROM timestamp_field) * interval '1 sec';
```

Demo:

```sql
test=> SELECT now()
test-> UNION ALL
test-> SELECT date_trunc('hour', now())
test->      + interval '2 min'
test->      + extract('seconds' FROM now()) * interval '1 sec';
              now              
-------------------------------
 2021-03-23 03:59:57.373279+01
 2021-03-23 03:02:57.373279+01
(2 rows)
```

Should be substantially faster than manipulating the text representation and casting back.